# Parar settimeuout al estar sobre div

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo este codigo:

```
function Menuopciones(pagina,menu) {
timeout = 600;
var thread; 
$("#"+pagina).mousemove(function(){ 
    $("#"+menu).removeClass('oculto').addClass('bounceIn');
    clearTimeout(thread);
    thread = setTimeout(mousestopped, timeout);
});
function mousestopped(){ $("#"+menu).removeClass('bounceIn').addClass('oculto'); };
$("#"+menu).hover(function(){ $(this).css("opacity", "1"); }, function(){ $(this).css("opacity", ""); clearTimeout(thread); });
}
```

lo que estoy intentando es que al estar sobre `$("#"+menu)` se pare el setimeout para que no me oculte el menu.

¿que puedo estar haciendo mal?

```js
function Menuopciones(pagina,menu) {
timeout = 600;
var thread; 
$("#"+pagina).mousemove(function(){ 
 $("#"+menu).removeClass('oculto').addClass('bounceIn');
 clearTimeout(thread);
 thread = setTimeout(mousestopped, timeout);
});
function mousestopped(){ $("#"+menu).removeClass('bounceIn').addClass('oculto'); };
$("#"+menu).hover(function(){ $(this).css("opacity", "1"); }, function(){ $(this).css("opacity", ""); });
$("#"+menu).draggable();
}
```

```css
#Pagina { width:500px; height:500px; background-color: #CCC; }

.oculto { display: none; }

.MenuDocumentos { position: absolute; width: 290px; height: 100px; margin: 0 0 0 -140px; left: 50%; top: 50%; text-align: center; font-size: 40px; padding: 15px 5px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32); border-radius: 10px; z-index: 999; -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; -o-animation-duration: 0.5s; -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s; animation-duration: 0.5s; }
.MenuDocumentos i { margin: 5px 10px; }
.DocGuardar:hover { color: green; }
.DocImprimir:hover { color: #2179ff; }
.DocEnviar:hover { color: #2179ff; }
.DocBorrar:hover { color: red; }
.MenuDocumentos select { 
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 10px 30px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; appearance: none; }

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn{0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale(.3)}50%{opacity:0.4;-webkit-transform:scale(1.05)}70%{-webkit-transform:scale(.9)}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1)}}
@-moz-keyframes bounceIn{0%{opacity:0;-moz-transform:scale(.3)}50%{opacity:0.4;-moz-transform:scale(1.05)}70%{-moz-transform:scale(.9)}100%{-moz-transform:scale(1)}}
@-o-keyframes bounceIn{0%{opacity:0;-o-transform:scale(.3)}50%{opacity:0.4;-o-transform:scale(1.05)}70%{-o-transform:scale(.9)}100%{-o-transform:scale(1)}}
@keyframes bounceIn{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale(.3)}50%{opacity:0.4;transform:scale(1.05)}70%{transform:scale(.9)}100%{transform:scale(1)}}
.bounceIn { -webkit-animation-name:bounceIn;-moz-animation-name:bounceIn;-o-animation-name:bounceIn;animation-name:bounceIn; opacity:0.4 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script>Menuopciones('Pagina','MenuOpciones');</script>

<div id="MenuOpciones" class="MenuDocumentos oculto">
 <i class="fas fa-check DocGuardar" title="Guardar"></i>
 <i class="fas fa-print DocImprimir" title="Imprimir"></i>
 <i class="far fa-paper-plane DocEnviar" title="Enviar"></i>
 <i class="fas fa-recycle DocBorrar"></i>
 <p><select>
  <option selected value="">Opciones</option>
  <option value="Verpedido">Ver</option>
  <option value="sinvalor">Imprimir</option>
  <option value="proforma">Imprimir 2</option>
  <option value="eliminar">Eliminar</option>
 </select></p>
</div>

<div id="Pagina"></div>
```

No consigo que en el snippet funcione, de hecho ahora en la web tampoco va, se conoce que tenia activado pagespeed y me estaba tirando de cache... voy a intentar arreglarlo y actualizo el código aqui

Comment: Y que error obtienes? que no esta funcionando como deberia?

Comment: que sigue ocultando el menu a pesar que estoy sobre el @LuisFernando

Comment: @Killpe por que no tratas de hacer un ejemplo que se pueda ejecutar en el snippet para poder ayudarte mejor ?

Comment: voy a intentarlo @CamiloVasquez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que debías hacer para "retener" la visibilidad del menú al estar sobre él era detener la ejecución del `setTimeout()` al momento de hacer el `hover` en el menú.

Te dejo tu código funcional.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Menuopciones(pagina, menu) {
        timeout = 600;
        var thread; 
        
        $("#"+pagina).mousemove(function(){
            $("#"+menu).removeClass('oculto').addClass('bounceIn');
            clearTimeout(thread);
            thread = setTimeout(mousestopped, timeout);
        });
        
        $("#"+menu).hover(function(){ 
            clearTimeout(thread);
        });

        $("#"+menu).draggable();

        function mousestopped(){ 
            $("#"+menu).removeClass('bounceIn').addClass('oculto'); 
        };
    }

    Menuopciones('Pagina','MenuOpciones');
});
```

```css
#Pagina { width:500px; height:500px; background-color: #CCC; }

.oculto { display: none; }

.MenuDocumentos { position: absolute; width: 290px; height: 100px; margin: 0 0 0 -140px; left: 50%; top: 50%; text-align: center; font-size: 40px; padding: 15px 5px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32); border-radius: 10px; z-index: 999; -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; -o-animation-duration: 0.5s; -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s; animation-duration: 0.5s; }
.MenuDocumentos i { margin: 5px 10px; }
.DocGuardar:hover { color: green; }
.DocImprimir:hover { color: #2179ff; }
.DocEnviar:hover { color: #2179ff; }
.DocBorrar:hover { color: red; }
.MenuDocumentos select { 
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 10px 30px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; appearance: none; }

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn{0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:scale(.3)}50%{opacity:0.4;-webkit-transform:scale(1.05)}70%{-webkit-transform:scale(.9)}100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1)}}
@-moz-keyframes bounceIn{0%{opacity:0;-moz-transform:scale(.3)}50%{opacity:0.4;-moz-transform:scale(1.05)}70%{-moz-transform:scale(.9)}100%{-moz-transform:scale(1)}}
@-o-keyframes bounceIn{0%{opacity:0;-o-transform:scale(.3)}50%{opacity:0.4;-o-transform:scale(1.05)}70%{-o-transform:scale(.9)}100%{-o-transform:scale(1)}}
@keyframes bounceIn{0%{opacity:0;transform:scale(.3)}50%{opacity:0.4;transform:scale(1.05)}70%{transform:scale(.9)}100%{transform:scale(1)}}
.bounceIn { -webkit-animation-name:bounceIn;-moz-animation-name:bounceIn;-o-animation-name:bounceIn;animation-name:bounceIn; opacity:0.4 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="MenuOpciones" class="MenuDocumentos oculto">
    <i class="fas fa-check DocGuardar" title="Guardar"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-print DocImprimir" title="Imprimir"></i>
    <i class="far fa-paper-plane DocEnviar" title="Enviar"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-recycle DocBorrar"></i>
    <p><select>
        <option selected value="">Opciones</option>
        <option value="Verpedido">Ver</option>
        <option value="sinvalor">Imprimir</option>
        <option value="proforma">Imprimir 2</option>
        <option value="eliminar">Eliminar</option>
    </select></p>
</div>

<div id="Pagina"></div>
```

Te recomiendo agregar tu código dentro de un evento `ready()` al `document` para que se ejecute una vez hayan cargado todos los elementos del sitio

Comment: Genial :) te quieroooo. Mil gracías.